# Select * from table using autogenerated id android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data from table by passing "id" number in where clause in
sqlite android, but getting empty result.

if i pass another field (name,number) as where clause. it's working fine, but not working for id.

Here's code for table :

```
public final String field_id = "id";
    public final String field_name = "name";
    public final String field_no = "no";

String create_query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + field_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
            +field_name+ " TEXT,"
            + field_no + " TEXT"
            + ")";
```

Here's the code for retrieving data

```
Cursor editData(String id)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "editData() called");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String search_query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE id=?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(search_query,new String []{id});
        if(cursor == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "cursor is NULL");
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

Here's how i am using this result

```
            DBHelper mDB = new DBHelper(this);
            Cursor mCursor = mDB.editData(id_name.getText().toString());

        if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            Log.d("EditActivity", "cursor moved to first");
            Log.d("TAG",String.format("%d", mCursor.getCount()));

            //Solved this by using Do...While loop instead of while
            while(mCursor.moveToNext())
            {
                Log.d("EditActivity", "cursor moved to next");
                Log.d(mCursor.getColumnName(0), mCursor.getString(0));
                Log.d(mCursor.getColumnName(1), mCursor.getString(1));
                Log.d(mCursor.getColumnName(2), mCursor.getString(2));
            }

        }
```

Can't we use auto-generated id in where clause in sqlite ?
any help on this ?

EDIT : i used do while loop instead of while & it worked

Comment: What's in your logcat? Why are you using a literal `id` in the select, when you're using the constant `field_id` elsewhere? Maybe you changed the name, and the table doesn't have a field name `id`? Lastly, why do you use a `rawQuery` rather than `query`?

Comment: logcat doesn't shows any error. & nope, m sure field name is not changed. will give a shot to query instead of rawQuery. thanks :)

Comment: Show the exact `id` value that you're using, and the database row that you think should match.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me before. Over database *id* is *numeric* and over the *function* is *string*.

The problem here is when you make this code:

```
String search_query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE id=?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(search_query,new String []{id});
```

The final query is ... `"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE id='1'";`
And what you really wanted was `"SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE id=1";`

This is my solution...

```
String search_query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE id="+id;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(search_query,null);
```

or

```
String search_query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE cast(id as text)=?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(search_query,new String []{id});
```

Comment: nothing worked. i tried the opposite like, casting String id to integer id but still didn't worked. and i don't see any reason for down voting my question & your answer :P

Comment: I didn't vote down your question, Actually... it is a good question, because it happened to me. Now, over editData, do you get a null cursor? or how do you notice that it did not have results?